# Batch file not generating output as expected?

Tags: batch-file

I have a simple dynamically generated batch file which follows the general format of:

```
@echo off
dir /a/s "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\files\clients\26\properties" | findstr "File(s)" > "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\scripts\foldersize\pFiles_26.dat" 
dir /a/s "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\files\clients\26\adverts" | findstr "File(s)" > "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\scripts\foldersize\aFiles_26.dat" 
dir /a/s "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\files\clients\28\properties" | findstr "File(s)" > "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\scripts\foldersize\pFiles_28.dat" 
dir /a/s "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\files\clients\28\adverts" | findstr "File(s)" > "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\scripts\foldersize\aFiles_28.dat" 
dir /a/s "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\files\clients\32\properties" | findstr "File(s)" > "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\scripts\foldersize\pFiles_32.dat" 
dir /a/s "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\files\clients\32\adverts" | findstr "File(s)" > "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\scripts\foldersize\aFiles_32.dat"
```

and so on... there's about 280 different folders it will need to run through... but the resulting files generated e.g. pFiles_26.dat or the like all end up as zero length files...

I know all these directories to have some content in them, so the results should all be varied...

As far as I can tell the commands aren't firing off the way they should... how can I ensure that these commands actually fire off, one by one, and result in files that contain the actual output of the recursive values of the numbers of files and total directory sizes??

Comment: Your code works for me, I get number of files/size of files in each folder and all folders.

Comment: @Endoro I've tried running it myself but all my files are zero bytes in length...

What could you be doing that's getting results?

Comment: If the files are empty, `findstr` did not find `file(s)`. Check code at the command prompt and with `echo on` option.

Comment: Could it be that you're not using an English-language version, so it's reporting "Fichier(s)" or `"File"` perhaps?

Comment: @Endoro I've run the individual commands and "file(s)" does appear in the generated output.

Comment: @PeterWright I'm using an English version of MS-DOS, it's how I roll... It's almost like the commands are firing off way too quickly but not allowing the previous command to run...

Is it possible to run each command as a separate background task so that they're not in the same queue, or better yet pace each command so that the first one must finish before the second one fires off?

Comment: test this : `findstr /i "File(s)"`

Comment: Well - should work, in theory. Funny thing though, theory...sometimes doesn't work according to theory. I'd like to know how this is being generated. It should run serially. I'm also curious about `/a/s`. Whereas it appears to work, it's a strange construct. The `/s` I can handle, but `/a` I've never seen - the `a` should be followed by a letter to make sense. You could ensure that each line gets individually fired by inserting a `timeout` between lines, perhaps. In any case, `something` should be output. Try popping-out the `findstr` and see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

Check you have write permission to the destination folder.  Try your code to a desktop folder, for example.  Mind you, you shouldn't get zero byte files either if that were the case.

Comment: I have write permissions, and the read-only permissions for the folder have been turned off... I thought that might have been the problem earlier on, but I still get the same result...

Comment: I've managed to find a solution, I've used the platform generating the code (ColdFusion) to loop through and execute concurrent threads to perform the directory listings...

`<cfloop list="#clients#" index="idx">
        <cfexecute name="c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" arguments='/c #APPLICATION.basepath#scripts\foldersize\dirP.bat #idx#'/>
        <cfexecute name="c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" arguments='/c #APPLICATION.basepath#scripts\foldersize\dirA.bat #idx#'/>
    </cfloop>`